# Parse Username and Domain name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a String like `CORP\tmothy` (general format is `CORP\<username>`) and I want to extract the word `tmothy` from this String

I am using `split` function , but its trying to split "`\t`" instead of "`\`". I have escaped the backslash using "`\\`", but still no luck.

This might be the case with any usernames starting with `n` , `r` , `b` etc as they are equivalent to `\n`,`\b`,`\r`

How do I overcome this with the JS script?

Comment: Can you post your JS code, the one where you're doing the `splits`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string 'CORP\tmothy', then doing .split('\') will definetely do the trick. Check this code:

```
var s = 'CORP\\tmothy'; // escaping backslash here prevents it to become TAB in the string variable
s.split('\\'); // returns ["CORP", "tmothy"]
```

You must be doing something wrong.